# Unhandled exception in c++ program for doubly linked list

Tags: c++, visual-studio, data-structures, linked-list

I wrote a program for doubly linked list in visual studio 2013, and it threw unhandled exception error at the line marked with comment: -

linked_list_double.h: -

```cpp
#pragma once
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *next, *prev;
};

template <typename T>
class doubleLinkedList
{
private:
    Node<T> *top;
public:
    doubleLinkedList()
    {
        top = nullptr;
    }

    void add(T data)
    {
        Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>;

        temp->prev = nullptr;
        temp->next = top;
        top->prev = temp;     //unhandled exception here
        top = temp;
    }

    void display()
    {
        Node<T> *temp;
        temp = top;
        std::cout<<"nullptr<--->\n";
        while(temp)
        {
            std::cout<<temp->data<<"<--->";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        std::cout<<"nullptr\n";
    }
};
```

main.cpp: -

```cpp
#include "linked_list_double.h"

int main()
{
    doubleLinkedList<int> L;

    L.add(3);
    L.add(4);
    L.display();

    return 0;
}
```

The error is: -

```
Unhandled exception at 0x011C4B79 in dataStructures2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000008.
```

I have never written a doubly linked list before. I am not sure if there any logical error in the program. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `main()` function that reproduces the issue?  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Also, why are you not debugging your code?   There is no excuse for not debugging your code, since you are using Visual Studio, has one of the best debuggers in the world, and the "Debug" option is right there on the main menu of the IDE.  If you did that, you should see that `top` is a null pointer and you're attempting to dereference it.

Comment: That didn't came to my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` is null on first add.  So any attempt to deference `top` while it's null is going to crash.

So insted of this:

```
    top->prev = temp;     //unhandled exception here
```

Do this:

```
if (top != nullptr)
{
   top->prev = temp;
}
```